# Anyone knows what is the meaning of shingai da na?

Tags: translation

> 心外だな,レイ

I searched in two sites and one said surprising the other unthinkable and vexing. How do i know what's right?

Comment: `two sites` -- You mean two *Japanese-English online dictionaries* or *automatic translators* ?

Comment: Aren't "surprising", "unthinkable", and "vexing" synonyms more or less?

Answer (score 3):

心外 is one word that means **both** surprising/unexpected **and** vexing/annoying/unpleasant at the same time. See how monolingual dictionaries define this:

> - 思いもよらないこと。思いがけないこと。思いがけない仕打ちや予想に反した悪い結果などに対して、腹立たしく感じたり残念に思ったりすること。 [デジタル大辞泉]
> - 思いもよらないこと、また、予期に反することが起こって、裏切られたような気持ちになること。
>     [明鏡国語辞典 第二版]

「心外だな、レイ」 on its own means レイ said something unexpected and it made the speaker upset.